# Connect R to a Power BI Service data flow

Tags: r, powerbi

Does anyone know if it is possible to connect R to a Power BI Service data flow?

I'd like to do all ETL in Power BI data flow and analytics on R. I know it's not possible to run R scripts in data flows, like in Power BI Desktop Power Query, so I could download the data to R Studio and work from there.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested in this, I don't see any ways to download it via API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dataflows), but I have heard of people being able to download PBIX files from PowerBI, and then theoretically you could read the data from the PBIX file using the PBIXr package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbixr/vignettes/explore.html). I don't know too much about it but I haven't been able to find any threads on this.